# Forcing div/page element to remain positioned at bottom of browser window

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm pretty sure this is something simple but I'm drawing a complete blank right now.

I have a jquery spinning wheel that needs to be fixed at the bottom of the browser window so that the top half of the wheel always shows at the base of the page, but I'll have to have a minimum required height so that it at least fits within the content area below the navigation. So, I have a minimum-height set on the containing div, but there has to be a way to do this so that it works more fluidly and I'm just stuck.

The page is built using twitter bootstrap, with a div for the spinning wheel.

Right now, I have that wheel div set to absolute position, but something is not working correctly - on a smaller height browser it disappears.

Eventually, I'll need to set the tablet and mobile styles, but for now I'd love someone to help me think this one through!

Here's the temp page:
http://bluetabby.com/rr/index9.html

**ETA: I knew I was being dense! So, of course position:fixed instead of absolute will keep it fixed where I want it at the bottom. HOWEVER - now I have the issue of it overflowing the navbar when the browser window is too short - am I missing something else obvious here that will prevent that and override the fixed positioning once it hits the top of its enclosing container? My brain is fried...

Here's the fixed position page url: http://bluetabby.com/rr/index10.html**

Here's the css for the wheel div and the wheel image:

```
    .wheel-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left:25%;
    bottom:0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.marker {
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
.wheel {

    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can give me some fresh ideas!!!!

Comment: Cant you just use a media query to make sure the wheel shrinks when the browser gets to short?

Comment: Yes, I can - I guess I was trying to find a way to make it easier and more universal.. I might just have to do that though

Comment: You could also try to use a max-height based on prosent

Comment: The max-height media query will work - thanks! it's just a little more work than I was hoping for - but it does the trick!